Best settings to compress a 4K 60fps ProRes 422HQ video to ~50GB HEVC using FFmpeg?
I recently upscaled a 1080p 60fps 90-minute video to 4K using Topaz. The output was set to ProRes 422HQ, resulting in a file size of 1.2TB. Naturally, I don’t want to keep the file this large and aim to compress it to around 50GB using H.265.
I based this target size on 90-minute 4K Blu-ray rips I have, though they aren’t 60fps, so I’m not entirely sure about the best approach. I’m looking for advice on compressing the video without losing much of the quality gained from the upscale. I want a good balance between quality and file size, with the end result being around 50GB.
Here’s the command I tried:
ffmpeg -i input.mov -c:v hevc_videotoolbox -q:v 30 -c:a copy ~/Movies/output.mp4

However, the output file was only 7GB, which is too small and doesn’t meet my needs. I’m using an M1 Pro, which is why I’m using videotoolbox.
Does anyone have suggestions for settings and commands that would achieve my goal? I’m looking for a good conversion from ProRes to HEVC that preserves the details and results in a file size around 50GB.

Reduce q:v and set -g X where X is number of frames for keyframe interval. Start with 120.
